# Is it possible to group Model fields in Django?

Tags: django, model

Working on a Calendar app, and would like each Event model instance to have one of the {allday|start,end} fields filled out.  That is, either the allday field entered, or the start+end fields, but not both.

How can I model this and have it work correctly in the admin app?  I'd like one of the group to be required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your model with all 3 fields, and override the clean method (called when validating the model) to check on your conditions:

```
def clean(self):
    if not self.allday: # allday not present
        if not self.start or not self.end: # start and/or end not present
            raise ValidationError('error message...')
    else:
        if self.start or self.end:     # allday present but also start and/or end
            raise ValidationError('error message...')
```

More information on `clean`: [Model.clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#django.db.models.Model.clean)